# Express app.get() detect all requests for certain file extensions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to be able to handle requests for any request for a .html file type. Is this possible?

Something like this:

```
// server.js
app.get('/*.html', (req, res) => {
  // do something whenever a request is made for an html file
});
```

Comment: are you trying to intercept requests for file that you have or just for every possible path that ends with ".html"? Do you want it to work also for subpaths like "/sub/path/file.html"? Try to explain better why are you doing this and what are you trying to achieve to get the best answer :)

Comment: Have a look at this. Does this answer your question? https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to match the path that you want like so. You can find more about routing here https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html.

```
app.get(/.*\.html$/, (req, res) => {
  // do something whenever a request is made for an html file
});
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape the second `.` so it's treated as a period, not a wildcard?

Comment: Yes you are right, i missused the `.` as a wildcard since i didn't escape it.